Components of the reaction forces against a fluid along the horizontal and vertical axes for slanted walls
I came to know that the reaction force (normal force) exerted by the walls of a vessel against a fluid is normal to the surface area of the vessel, which is the nature of a normal force.
Also, at any point, the pressure at a point depends on the height of the fluid exposed to the atmosphere. So even if a point is just vertically downward, it still experiences a pressure of $\rho gh$ (with fluid density $\rho$), even though the fluid above doesn't have a height of $h$. The pressure gets contributed due to the vertical component of the normal force by the walls of the container.

So the pressure at point C (which lies at the base) equals $\rho gh$ by the laws of fluid hydrostatics. But the pressure due to the fluid above is $\rho g(h-d)$. Since the walls of the container are exerting a vertical force to make the pressure at point C $\rho gh$, the pressure exerted vertically by the wall vertically above C should be $\rho gd$. Also, the pressure exerted by the wall horizontally should also be equal to $\rho gd$ to maintain equilibrium within the fluid.
So does the wall of the container exert a pressure which is the resultant of these two pressures and hence greater than $\rho gd$ normal to its surface area?
If so, would the particles colliding with the wall in the normal direction experience a pressure greater than $\rho gd$?

You’re drawing forces and calling them pressures. This is invalid and results in inconsistency, as you’ve shown here. The wall applies a distributed force to maintain a gauge pressure at any point of $\rho g d$, where $d$ is the depth below the reference open surface. One can’t take a component of this force and equate it to a pressure, because the two are distinct concepts.

@Chemomechanics yeah I used those two terms in an incorrect interchangeable manner. I edited those. But if I replace the force vector, then is it that the pressure exerted horizontally and vertically are both (densitygd)?

Force is a vector that you can take the components of. Pressure corresponds to a rank-two tensor that doesn’t permit the same operation. If you wish, you can decompose a force $F = \rho g dA$ (over a small vessel region of area $A$ at depth $d$) into $F\sin \theta$ and $F\cos\theta$, for instance. But neither acts independently on any region of the fluid.

If this makes sense, I’ll convert it into an answer. If it doesn’t, please expand on what’s unclear.

@Chemomechanics also this this answer states that the force exerted by the wall in a vertical direction accounts to the pressure of $\rho gh$

To be honest didn't wanted the force factor to come up. Can you just explain it by the pressure term itself or both how the forces act horizontally and vertically and what are their values and the pressure as I am being now exposed two variants. Not knowing the other one would not let me be unsatisfied.

Please check that you’ve linked to the answer you intended; I don’t see “vertical direction” in that answer. “Pressure” in a fluid element refers to forces acting on all sides; along the surface of a container wall, the force is applied normal—perpendicular—to the wall. It still appears that you’re trying to resolve a stress state like a vector, but it’s not a vector.

@Chemomechanics but can you say what is the equation of the force that is being exerted horizontally and vertically. Might be I can figure out what's going on. Also this states that he walls of the container exert forces on the enclosed water equal to those which had been exerted by the surrounding water. Equation of this force and component of it along the horizontal and vertical axis.

As I mentioned above, you can resolve the normal force $F$ into $F\sin\theta$ and $F\cos\theta$ if you wish. However, neither of them is acting independently to exert the pressure. In other words, you can’t say that the pressure is $F\sin\theta/A$ in one direction and $F\cos\theta/A$ in the orthogonal direction, because there’s no horizontal or vertical sections in the sloped region to apply those normal forces. There’s only a pressure $P$ and a normal force $F=PA$ at any region $A$ of the container wall that sustains that pressure. Does this make sense?

Can you give an analogy so that I can understand better.
Till now I am convinced that the wall of the container exerts a pressure P = $\rho gd$ which is isotropic and cannot be given direction. Also the normal force exerted by the wall is F=PA where P is $\rho gd$. But if the force exerted has a direction which is normal to the surface, how does pressure exerted is isotropic.

@Chemomechanics does understanding this needs that i understand the stress tensor in detail which I am completely unaware of. That is in itself a huge separate concept

@Chemomechanics I went through this to understand tensor, but still not able to understand your comment - The wall applies a distributed force to maintain a gauge pressure at any point of ρgd. Not able to convince myself how the force is different than the Pressure or the entire thing.

It's not necessary to get into tensors if you'd prefer not to. Instead, you can treat pressure as a scalar (that ends up being negative one-third the trace of the stress tensor). This scalar is the property of a point in the fluid; it has no direction. A direction arises when you select a surface, such as a container wall. Then, the pressure is the force applied normal to this surface per unit area. The force can be divided into vector components, but the pressure cannot.

This point and related points are discussed in 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8. If any of these explanations is confusing, move on to the next.

Thank you for our discussion; as indicated and for simplicity, I'll avoid introducing tensors. We can get along fine by treating the pressure as a scalar, a directionless property of any point in the fluid. If a surface—such as a container wall—is introduced, then the pressure corresponds to a force per unit area. That force is a vector acting normal to the surface, and the area can also be treated as a vector through its surface normal. The ratio produces the scalar pressure, as discussed in the links above (example; example; example).
Ultimately, I think you may be looking for something like the following:

To set this up, it's important to address a problem in the question's chain of reasoning. It arises within
(1) "So even if a point is just vertically downward [from a container wall], it still experiences a pressure of ρgh (with fluid density ρ), even though the fluid above doesn't have a height of h."
and
(2) "The pressure gets contributed due to the vertical component of the normal force by the walls of the container."
and
(3) "the pressure exerted vertically by the wall vertically above C should be ρgd."
Statement (1) is correct. Both the weight of the fluid and the constraint of the container act to produce the pressure field $P = \rho gh$.
Statement (2) starts to become misleading. Pressure is applied by the container wall's normal force in its entirety—both horizontal and vertical components. For a wall region of area $A$, one could resolve the normal force $F = PA$ into the components $F \sin \theta$ and $F \cos \theta$ (with wall angle $\theta$). However, it would be incorrect to say that any arbitrary fluid region below is acted on by only the vertical component. Instead, a small fluid region next to the wall is acted on by the entire force $F$, in addition to fluid forces from all other directions. A small fluid region away from the wall is acted on by forces in all directions from the surrounding fluid. In both cases, the entire set of forces in all directions makes up the pressure field in that region. In no case does either $F \sin \theta$ or $F \cos \theta$ alone act on any arbitrary fluid region.
For these reasons, statement (3) is also potentially misleading. We can't select only the vertical (or horizontal) component of the wall force and follow it vertically (or horizontally) to some other arbitrary part of the fluid and say that only that component applies a pressure. The problem with saying "pressure induced vertically" is evident from the question; we then could just as well say "pressure induced horizontally," and then there's the potential tendency to try to add these two pressures or to combine them like vectors, which is invalid. The wall plays a part in inducing a directionless pressure $P=\rho g h$ everywhere in the fluid. It does this by applying an inward force perpendicular to the wall's surface.
We often hear statements like "The pressure in a fluid corresponds to the weight of the fluid above it." This is true in a sense, but it as well can be misleading because it leads to the misconception that pressure can only act downward, or that forces are transmitted downward only. Instead, pressure arises from forces acting on all sides; if any direction were missing, the water would start to flow spontaneously (as discussed and illustrated in the links above) and wouldn't stop until forces did act on all sides.
So for now, I recommend resisting the tendency to say that pressure is applied in a certain direction, unless you're referring to a certain area $A$ and the corresponding force perpendicular to that area. If you catch yourself saying that pressure is applied vertically (or in any direction), then force yourself to draw the corresponding area—which for a vertical force would be a section of a horizontal plane. In this case, there's no horizontal plane present in the sloping container walls, which is an indication that those walls can't apply a vertical force alone.
OK, now to the figure above. If you're familiar with free-body diagrams, you can draw a free-body diagram of any conceptual region of a fluid and consider the forces acting on its boundaries, even if sloped (example). The figure shows (left) a 2D visualization of a container wall holding in a fluid; (center) a schematic of the relevant geometry, with trigonometry used to determine the boundary surface areas; and (right) a true free-body diagram of the forces acting on the fluid parcel, with the wall's normal force resolved into horizontal and vertical components. The region is small enough that the weight is negligible and the vertical positions are all essentially at the same depth. For dimensional consistency with the real 3D world, assume that all images show a region with unit depth into the screen.
Since the fluid is at equilibrium, the components of the wall force need to be counteracted by equal and opposite forces applied by the surrounding fluid on the other boundaries. These forces are specific to the boundaries drawn here, and association of the pressure with a force requires consideration of the boundary orientation and its area. Consistent over all three boundaries, the pressure is $\frac{F}{A}=\frac{F\cos\theta}{A\cos\theta}=\frac{F\sin\theta}{A\sin\theta}=P$. It can now be appropriate to associate the pressure with the vertical force $F\cos\theta$ because we've explicitly defined a surface—and that surface in this case has an area of $A\cos\theta$ because the conceptual fluid region is a right triangle (in 3D, a right triangular prism) with hypotenuse corresponding to area $A$.
What if we consider a region farther down (but again small, and still at are same approximate depth, so the weight and pressure variation with depth is still negligible)?

On the upper surface (with area $A\cos\theta$), Newton's third law tells us that the applied force must be equal and opposite to the force on the downward surface of the right triangle, which is $F\cos\theta$. In fact, the forces on all sides must be $F\cos\theta$ to maintain a pressure of $\frac{F\cos\theta}{A\cos\theta}=P$.
But we could just as well have drawn a region with arbitrary surface areas $A^\prime$:

To maintain the pressure $P$ at the same approximate depth, the side forces are now $FA^\prime/A$. Importantly, the $\cos\theta$ factor that arose when finding the vector components of the original wall force $F$ has disappeared. It was applicable only for the right-triangle geometry adjacent to the wall. Thus, $F\cos\theta$ is not a general factor that applies to other arbitrary fluid regions.
I believe this resolves the issue in which it may have appeared that the pressure must be different in different directions; the confusion might have arisen because of the problems, emphasized above, that arise when (1) ascribing a direction to pressure—along with corresponding forces—without defining a suitable corresponding area, and then (2) trying to combine these apparent directional components as if they're vectors when they aren't.
